# COUNTA(SPLIT) function to count number of words not working on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am currently working on a Google Sheets project, and I'm facing a challenge with counting the number of words in a cell.

I have tried using the following formula:

```
=IF(A1="", "", COUNTA(SPLIT(A1, " ")))
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working as expected, and I'm not getting the error "Formula parse error".

[image]

Sample data:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17Zel32C06M49KkLk2YQ6HQqEP68yutF8WZsE551ZxKc/edit?usp=sharing

The objective is to count the number of words in cell A2, excluding any leading or trailing spaces. However, the formula is not providing the desired result. I have tried other formulas such as

```
= LEN ( A1 ) - LEN ( SUBSTITUTE ( A1, " ", "" ) ) + 1
```

Could someone please help me with a reliable formula or an alternative approach to accurately count the number of words?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the commas to semi-colons, according to your locale ;)

[image]

```
=IF(A3="";"";COUNTA(SPLIT(A3;" ")))

= LEN ( A3 ) - LEN ( SUBSTITUTE ( A3; " "; "" ) ) + 1
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked great. Why do I have to change commas to semmi-colons? Would you mind explaining that a little bit? I didn't use to have this probleam. Thanks!

Comment: [this article](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/sheets-location/) (on syntax difference) should be helpful:

Comment: @djur -the article shared explains the differences; why it changed in your particular case, I don't know. Maybe you changed the language or zone region in your Google settings?, Or you're working on a shared file?